# Add single quote within the table name in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to add single quot within the table name in a single row

I have design below query

```
select 
    upper(listagg(table_nm,',') within group (order by table_nm)) as table_nm 
from
    db.tb
where
    subject_area='TLS'
```

and got the output as

```
TLS_TASK,TLS_USER
```

but i want the output as

```
'TLS_TASK','TLS_USER'
```

please help me on this

Comment: What do you need this for? How is the result going to be used? It looks almost like you are trying to prepare a string to pass to an IN condition (as a list of tables to check against, in a WHERE clause). If that's why you need this, then it won't work anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 3 more quotes to enclose a quote. `''` within quotes represents a single quote.

```
     SELECT Upper(Listagg(''''
                     ||table_nm
                     ||'''', ',')
               within GROUP (ORDER BY table_nm)) AS table_nm
FROM   db.tb
WHERE  subject_area = 'TLS';
```

Answer (score 2):

simply concat a quote `'` before and after `table_nm`

```
select 
    upper(listagg(''''||table_nm||'''',',') within group (order by table_nm)) as table_nm 
from
    db.tb
where
    subject_area='TLS'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Indent the above code is giving error "'": invalid identifier

Comment: Not sure which language you are familiar with, but in Oracle SQL you don't wrap strings within double-quotes. You wrap them within single quotes, so - for that reason - literal single quotes must be escaped by doubling them. -1 from me, but it would be best to delete this answer altogether - I can't see how it can help anyone.

Comment: Sorry, I write to fast ;-)